# The difference between"move over " and "get out of the way"

Tags: differences

I have searched for the difference between the two idioms "move over" and "get out of the the way", and I found no results.

Are they interchangeable when we politely ask for some physical space?

Comment: They're interchangeable in the sense that you shouldn't use *either* when you want to *politely* ask for some personal space. If you want to roughly demand someone remove himself from the direct oath from you to your objective, you can also use either, but *get out of the way* is harsher. But neither is "nice".

Comment: You need to include more context in your question. How are you planning to use them in a sentence? Both idioms are quite rude. "Move over" usually refers to someone sitting or standing beside you, while "get out of the way" refers to someone blocking your forward path of movement. You would *at least* need to couch them in *very* polite language before either use was acceptable. The exception, of course, is if you are a police officer or other "first responder" using them as commands in an emergency situation.

Comment: Yes,  of course,  i wouldnt use them solely but i would say"could you please move over"or "would you please get out of the way".My question here is"Are they interchangeable in the above mentioned contexts "?

Comment: In that regard, "move over" would be more polite. "Get out of the way" has an implied accusation — you are in the way. "Move over" is simply a request that they move.

Comment: A more polite version is "scooch over."

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on context. "Get out of the way" includes information that "move over" lacks: WHY you want them to move. You might tell someone to move over so they can improve their view, or for some other reason. "Get out of the way" is more specific — you are in the way and I want you to move so you're no longer in the way.